# R - apply survfit to a list and plot with corresponding names

Tags: r, list, plot, apply, survival-analysis

I have a list of named dataframes:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

surv.days<- runif(n = 50, min = 0, max = 500)
censor<- sample(c(0,1), 50, replace=TRUE)
survdata<- data.frame(surv.days, censor)
survlist<- list(survdata, survdata)
names(survlist)<- c("name1", "name2")
rm(survdata, censor, surv.days)
```

I want to run a survfit on each dataframe and then generate several plots (I put only one here for the sake of simplicity), each plot with the corresponding title. I think Map is the way to do it, so:

```
titles<- names(survlist)
```

Then I define the function that I want to use to run the survival analysis and plots:

```
survival.function<- function(survivaldata, datanames){
  sfit<- survfit(Surv(surv.days, censor)~1, data=survivaldata)
  ggsurvplot(sfit, conf.int=TRUE, risk.table=TRUE,
             surv.median.line = "v",
             title=datanames,
             risk.table.height=.25)
}
```

And try to apply it:

```
Map(survival.function, survlist, titles)
```

But the idea didn't work:
"Error in eval(fit$call$data) : object 'survivaldata' not found "
Is there a way to properly assign the objects to the survival functions?
Thank you!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the error message seems to be misleading, at least to my reading. It appears to point to the error being in the call to `survfit` when in fact it's an error within `ggsurvplot` as can be seen from the output of `traceback()`. I first tried to change the name of the object passed to `survival.function`. Then no error. But also no plot. So also added a `print` call inside `survival.function`. I'll attache the first of the two plots that result.

```
survival.function<- function(data, datanames){
  sfit<- survfit(Surv(surv.days, censor)~1, data=data)
  print( ggsurvplot(sfit, conf.int=TRUE, risk.table=TRUE,
             surv.median.line = "v",
             title=datanames,
             risk.table.height=.25) )
}
```

[image]

I wish I could better explain why this hack works. (I'm only guessing at the cause on the basis of the error message and `traceback()`-results.) I'm using the fact that the `name` of the "missing" object was "data". It's possible this is a semantic bug in the `ggsurvplot` and you would be doing a favor to the maintainer of the package to send him a link to this fully documented example. I wonder whetehr there would be possible improvement if the maintainer changed the code so that the list member name were not accessed from the environment with `$data` but rather `[[data]]`.

Comment: This stops working when you remove the "surv.days" object from the global env. (something that I should have done in the original example), so I edited the original post by adding
    `rm(survdata, censor, surv.days)`

Comment: I see that as further evidence that the ggsurvplot function is failing to properly extract and handle the internals of a survfit object. The maintainer should be questioned.